# DNS lookup using Pcap and C

Tags: dns

I'm trying to perform DNS attacks using Pcap library and C code. Currently I can: 1. Read a DNS query 2. Based on the DNS query, create a DNS answer and inject the malicious IP. 3. Inject the fake response back into the network.

While using Wireshark, i can see my packet is successfully injected to the network. Yet the IP address is not changed i.e. on ns lookup, it says 'connection times out;no servers could be reached'. Instead it accepts the actual response from the DNS server.

Any idea why this isn't working? Where could i be going wrong?

Comment: What operating system for the DNS client are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the transaction ID matches. Also depending on the client you may need to spoof the source IP address. TTL can matter but not if it is small, i.e. Over 1 week can be blocked, as per RFC 1035.

Also note that the first valid DNS response is the one that get accepted. So you will need to ensure that you reply is faster than the other server.

This may also help http://www.sans.org/reading_room/whitepapers/dns/dns-spoofing-man-middle_1567.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is something wrong with your generated packet. Are you updating the required flags and setting the correct sections? And copying the transaction ID correctly?
You could try capturing a real answer and modifying that, before creating a new answer.

As a sidenote, I'd recommend using Python for this exercise, much simpler coding ;-)

Comment: It's one of my module assignments and i haveto use Pcap and C only. :)

I checked in wireshark, my packet and the orginal packet is captured. But the client updates based on the original packet rather than my fake one.

Also, as per wireshark, the packet is generated and the Transaction ID seems to be the same. Flags are set and are same as the orginal response. (able to compare my fake response and the original response from the DNS server. All fields are the same!)

Does the TTL field matter? I've set it to a random of 58seconds.

Comment: Also, when the victim gets two DNS responses (fake and original) how does it decide which one to use?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you can make your fake server respond to packets directly sent to it so that it's not having to "win the race" to arrive first.

You can then use simple `dig` commands to ensure that you're actually conformant with the DNS protocol specifications.

Apart from the other things mentioned here, you'll also need to ensure that your packets are consistent at the IP layer too.  If you're spoofing a response you'll need to ensure that the IP checksum field has been correctly calculated - if it's incorrect your packets may never reach the intended victim machine's higher levels.